# Android: Read-only storage behaves like writable

Tags: android, storage, readonly, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an application where I test all storages whether they are accessible. As you probably know, Google starts to limit access to external storages. So Kitkat devices can have read-only storages that have writable access only to application specific directory (/Android/data/...).

I test paths of all storages whether they are writable by testing:

```
if(new File("/storage_root_path/").canWrite() && new File("/storage_root_path/AppDir/").canWrite())
{
  //storage is writable
}
else
{
  //storage is readonly
}
```

/AppDir/ is directory of my app on root of storage. These tests work well for most devices. But I have one user with Samsung Galaxy S4 SGH-M919 (Kitkat) and both tests return true on his external sd card. But the storage is not writable.

Is there any other way how to determine that storage is read-only on Kitkat ? I can try to create folder but I would like to have some better and faster solution.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Confirm. One should really check file for writability, `File.canWrite()` doesn't help. I'm using this kind of function:

```
private boolean isFileWritable(File file) {
    try {
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        FileChannel fc=raf.getChannel();
        FileLock fl=fc.lock();
        fl.release();
        fc.close();
        raf.close();
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }

}
```